# Make horizontal scrolling parent to take up the width of its childs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox

I am trying to make a horizontal scroller using `flex`. The problem is the parent of flex items is not taking the complete width of all the childs.

The problem is that the childs are using `flex: 0 0 9%` and there is no fixed width defined on any of the parents because I want to make it flexible.
So, I have made a simple structure in codepen to show what I am trying to do.

https://codepen.io/khubaibqaiser/pen/WVGZZW

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  $("#itemContainer1, #itemContainer2, #itemContainer3").append(`<div class="item">Child ${i}</div>`)
}
```

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 0 9%;
  background: green;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div id="itemContainer1" class="row">
  </div>
  <div id="itemContainer2" class="row">
  </div>
  <div id="itemContainer3" class="row">
  </div>
</div>
```

Ideally the width of `.row` div should take up the width of all its children.

Comment: if youa dd overflow auto to the itemcontainer it will work what you waNt to achieve issue is scroll will come

Comment: so instead of adding the css which you want in item-container add to item

Comment: Yeah, I know but that's not what I want to achieve. I want `.parent` to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

The horizontal scroll was there, maybe because of your background color in parent, change the color to blue, then you will be done.
[image]

Comment: The issue is not with the horizontal scroll but with the `.row` div not taking up the entire width of its childs. If you scroll a little to the right you would see that `.row` (colored Yellow) has width less than the width of its childs.